# Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system on Ubuntu 22.10 / WSL2

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cuda

Premising that I’m using “Microsoft Windows 11 [Version 10.0.22000.1219]”,I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on top of it and then I’ve upgraded Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 and I’ve upgraded the driver for my RTX 2080 ti on the host OS. After this,I have installed CUDA inside the WSL2 / Ubuntu following this mini tutorial :

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_network

These are the commands that I have issued :

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

at this point I did :

```
apt install nvidia-utils-510
```

because without installing this package,it won’t find the utility nvidia-smi. But this is the error that I’ve got next :

```
# nvidia-smi  

Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system
Failed to properly shut down NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system
```

what should I do now ? The driver installed on the host OS is version : 31.0.15.2686

Comment: The microsoft guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-cuda-in-wsl) suggests you need a specific NVIDIA driver for the host OS, but isn't clear on where/how you get one

Comment: someone has been able to do that,you can read here : https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9166#issuecomment-1319575768 ; but I haven't been able to replicate. I don't understand where to get the repos he talked about. I've installed every package on his list,but I still get the error.